# Ошибка запуска только на реальном iPhone

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8

При попытке запуска приложения на подключенном iPhone после компиляции Xcode выдает такую ошибку:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/A70912F0-CBEA-4522-904F-31DC0CF1E367/AppName.app (loaded)' with name 'UIViewController-BYZ-38-t0r' and directory 'Main.storyboardc''
>
> First throw call stack:
>
> (0x184801900 0x183e6ff80 0x184801848 0x1899bd1ac 0x189c1a108 0x189c1a268 0x18979d580 0x18956937c 0x18979c364 0x1897995c0 0x185db7790 0x185db7b10 0x1847b8efc 0x1847b8990 0x1847b6690 0x1846e5680 0x189562580 0x18955cd90 0x1000d18cc 0x1842868b8)
>
> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Однако при запуске на симуляторе все в норме.

Как и чем это лечится?

Comment: удалите приложение с девайса и сделайте clean в xcode.

Comment: Помогло при выполнении: 1) Удаление с устройства 2) Clean 3) Build 4) Запуск на устройстве. Спасибо!!

Comment: с позволения сконвертирую в ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Иногда xcode ведет себя странно, в частности не перезаписывает xib файлы на устройство. В частности переименованные могут остаться под старыми именами, измененные могут не записаться и тогда модификации не применятся, и так далее.

Чтобы это починить:

- удалить приложение с устройства
- сделать clean в xcode
- скомпилировать и запустить заново

Answer (score -1):

удали `DerivedData` (путь есть в настройках XCode, во вкладке Locations)